# EC2 Multiple website on one instance, load balance

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-web-services, lamp, amazon-elastic-ip

I have a question. My instance is currently using LAMP STACK by Bitnami, the first site is LAMP, the second is Magneto STACK by bitnami, My focus is on Magneto Stack. I was thinking of having the instance to run on Magneto Stack by bitnami and host my the other site on magneto, not sure if it can work out as it requires lamp :(

Another is , i have one IP already, do i need to create another elastic IP for my new site(magneto) and attach it to the same instance to be able to view the site? Or by editing virtual host will do? Meaning i set the new domain to the first elastic ip?

Quite new to Amazon here. My plan is to have my first website hosted while its in development. My focus is on magneto, the one running alive for consumer. For best , i believe i will have two instance each for one domain? But does load balance work if i have that?

Load balance means using of CPU power right? so i believe it can be shared? 
Instance 1 Host Domain A , Instance 2 Host Domain B - Can i load balance them together just incase if one requires more power?

Will totally appricaite your response and Advice. Thank you!

Comment: Allow me to clarify a few things: 1) A LAMP stack is simply an operating system (Linux), a web server (Apache), a database (MySQL), and a dynamic language (PHP). Magento is written in PHP and runs on a LAMP stack. 2) You can only associate one IP address to instances that are not in VPC. 3) VirtualHosts will let you run multiple websites from a single IP - however this may present some problems with SSL 4) You typically load balance between identical instances - a request can potentially go to any instance in the cluster, so all instance must be able to handle the request.

Comment: @cyberx86 , lets say i Stop the server, get snapshot, launch new Instance and Load balance but wont the data be on two different EBS? Its a e-commerce site, possible to sync or something?

Comment: If you have multiple database servers, you will need to setup replication, which will keep them in sync. Additionally, you should be able to freeze your database for a moment to take a snapshot, and not have to turn the server off completely (turning the server off is ideal, but can sometimes be avoided). In a larger setup, you would normally have your web servers running on separate instances from your database servers. At any point in time, all the servers that you will load balance between need to be in (nearly) the same state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, You are confusing a Cloud based application (which can use the computing power of different nodes in it's infrastructure) with a load balancer.

Load Balancer is a very simple mechanism. It will distribute your traffic among the nodes which are behind the load balancer on the bases of different mechanisms. Well, by default it's a round robin, in which the Load Balancer will distribute your traffic equally among the nodes behind it. For ex- if you have 2 nodes running behind a load balancer, and you send 100 hits to the load balancer, then it send 50 hits to node 1 and 50 hits to node 2, one by one.

> Load balance means using of CPU power right? so i believe it can be
>   shared? Instance 1 Host Domain A , Instance 2 Host Domain B - Can i
>   load balance them together just incase if one requires more power?

No, it's not possible. A normal load balancer doesn't even know about the states of the machine. There are few other Load balancers which can read the health of the machine and then redirect the traffic to the less loaded machine, but I don't think Amazon provides any such functionality.

Also, for a load balancer to work, you should have your application deployed on both of the nodes are any point of time.

Comment: ,Okay, lets say i Stop the server, get snapshot, launch new Instance and Load balance but wont the data be on two different EBS? Its a e-commerce site, possible to sync or something?